# Flutter Image fit alignment

Tags: flutter

Currently there are two ways I show image with BoxFit `contain` and `cover`. However I feel they are not the best way for my needs.

[image]

[image]

What I want is maybe the combination of both, ***the guy's head to be visible and the image still fill the available width yet the height doesn't change.***

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to stretch the image to fit the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context of what exactly you are trying to do, what you are asking sounds as some basic unsolved logic. However, if you will always have the guy and it is this picture.

Then you can do Stack and put that text below over the picture and brutally hide part of the picture you do not want to be seen.

Note. Don’t worry if picture is bigger then Stack, clip by default will cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Try BoxFit.fill.It will fill the box by distorting the source's aspect ratio.

```
Container(
width: 200,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I don't want it to get distorted. I prefer to have result like the first image with the full head shown (while the hand is missing)

Comment: The above method will fill the 100% of the container's width with height constant.